# Capistrano 3 Role specific tasks

Tags: ruby, deployment, roles, capistrano3

I've switched from Capistrano 2 to Capistrano 3 recently, a lot has changed, and I'm having some troubles trying to adapt the new Capistrano to what it was being done with Capistrano 2 in the project I'm working on.

The biggest problem I'm facing at the moment is filtering by roles. I know you can do:

```
ROLES=web,worker cap production deploy
```

but if you have a single server with all the roles, that seems to do nothing really.

With Capistrano 2 I could run:

```
cap worker deploy
```

and all worker tasks would be applied. Capistrano 2 had the roles specified on the tasks and if the role wasn't requested the tasks was skipped (in most cases). However it does not seem the case for Capistrano 3, the filter is great on a multi server environment where you have specific servers for each role. But if servers share a role or if there's a single one, it gets a bit weird. In the new Capistrano tasks seems to check whether there is a host with a given role rather than checking if the task should run or not based on the role. It seems to me that ROLES is intended to limit the servers rather than the tasks.

So I wonder if this is possible in Capistrano 3. Another way of viewing this is grouping tasks under a name. I would like to select which group of tasks are being executed.

I can achieve this with some tinkering, I could check if ROLES is present and skip a task or not based on it, I could select which recipes to load depending on role, I could dynamically attach the tasks based on the ROLES var, or maybe group the tasks in role named files and do that dynamic loading depending on ROLES, etc, but perhaps there's something I'm missing.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to me that ROLES is intended to limit the servers rather than the tasks.

Yes, that is exactly right. In Capistrano 3, tasks have no relation to roles whatsoever. Within a task, commands can be executed on servers that match a certain role. When you filter using ROLES, you limit the servers where the commands are run, but you don't limit the tasks themselves.

One way you could limit tasks is to define your own high-level task that invokes the tasks you want.

For example:

```
# In deploy.rb
task "worker" do
  invoke "task1"
  invoke "task2"
  # etc.
end
```

This defines a `worker` task that in turn executes a specific list of tasks, which can be whatever you want. Then you can run:

```
cap production worker
```

Which will run all these worker-related tasks on your production server.